# How to Insert multiple rows using Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

INSERT INTO Autori
VALUES ('Ken Follett', 1949, NULL, 'UK'), ('Micheal Connelly', 1956, NULL, 'USA'), ('Dan Brown',1964,NULL,'USA'),('Guido Sgardoli',1965,NULL,'IT'),('J. K. Rowling',1965,NULL,'UK'),('Stephen King',1947,NULL,'USA');

I don't know why, when I try to execute this query in MS Access, it says to me: "Expected semicolon at the end of the SQL statement"

How can I fix it?

Comment: You can do it by `VBA` looping.

Comment: Or use UNION syntax to build dataset of 6 records which will then be source for INSERT SELECT action. But surely normal data entry would be simpler than constructing a query with these static inputs. So what are you really trying to accomplish?